# Facebook API: I can't post a message to friend's wall or an other's wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I don't know why i can use `$post=$facebook->api('/me/feed','post','message');` to post a message on my wall (just message, no link,  no video, no photo), but when i replace 'me' by my friend_id or other_id, i can't post a message, although my app had permission to need to post a message on feed.

Answer (score 1):

Posting on wall of the user´s friends is a deprecated functionality and will not be available anymore very soon, because in 99% of the cases it´s unwanted and spam.

See Roadmap:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

```
Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API
```

So, if you create a new app, the "February 2013 Breaking Changes" will already be activated and it´s not possible anymore. This is mostly for spam reasons, no serious app posts on a friends wall.

Comment: But when i use graph api explorer, i still post a message on user's friend

Comment: did you select your new app in the api explorer? also the graph api explorer might work a bit different. fact is that it´s deprecated functionality and should not be used anymore.

Comment: So, about send a private message, is it not available? If not, i must do how to api to send a private message

Comment: that´s a different story, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ - else, there is only the send button. but that´s not an api function.

Comment: so, i must copy all code and paste into my app, after i must replace id_app, id_serect, user_id, but i can't see id_friend to send message. Can you guide me?

Comment: copy code? what are you talking about? i just gave you the link to the official facebook docs for the chat api, just read it if you really want to send personal messages to users ;)

Comment: btw, this is off topic, your question has been answered already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yet it is possible after Facebook has build their new roadmap in Feb, 2013. Just implement GarphAPI ans ASIHTTPRequest in ur project and use below code to POST text with image on friends wall...

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/photos?access_token=%@",[FRIEND_ID], fbGraph.accessToken];

    UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic, 1);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"This is Sample Text" forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setData:picData forKey:@"data"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:fbGraph.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

This will work as 100% cheers. I am using this right now...And by the way import FBGraph.h and ASIFormDataRequest.h into your implementation file.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: Sorry...@kev thnx for ur concern...I have did it coz I thought people know about it...next time I will avoid it..