# Posting a message to a friend's wall using the app access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get my app to post to a friend's wall. I tried using the FB.api method but I discovered that using that has been disabled.

Then I tried using the FB.ui feed dialog but then I discovered that the message parameter was deprecated, and was taken out because facebook wanted its users to enter text. And even when the user enters text, the message never gets posted to that user's wall.

So after doing alot more research I saw that another option was to create a custom action type. And in doing so I discovered that to take this approach my app needs an app access token.

So I tried using the following means:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token','get',
{client_id:'XXXXXXX', client_secret:'XXXXXXXXXXX', grant_type:'client_credentials'},
function(response) {
});
```

which is in no way different from what is in the documentation :

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &grant_type=client_credentials
```

I get errors like :

'Uncaught ReferenceError: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not defined' when I use

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url : 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
params : {
 client_id : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 client_secret : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 grant_type : 'client_credentials'
},
success : function(response, opts) {
},
failure : function(response, opts) {
}
```

});

OR

{type : 'http', message : 'unknown error'} when I use

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token','get',
{client_id:'XXXXXXX', client_secret:'XXXXXXXXXXX', grant_type:'client_credentials'},
function(response) {
});
```

Now the documentation says that when I do the following :

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &grant_type=client_credentials
```

I should get the following in my response object :

access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

Now from what I have done it appears I have followed the direction of the documentation but my question is why am I not getting the correct output as the documentation says?

Please help.

Comment: post to friend wall is deprecated, please google it before asking question next time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955488/facebook-api-i-cant-post-a-message-to-friends-wall-or-an-others-wall

Comment: OR You can do this as indicated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/, it's not related to access token. Yo can add parameter "to", such as https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&to=FRIEND_USER_ID&link=https://www.google.com/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=lala&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=http://example.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

`FB.api` works from the graph.facebook.com endpoint so you don't need to add the `graph.facebook.com` explicitly.

I'm not at a computer right now but I'm thinking the call is more like

```
FB.api('oauth/access_token'
```

Though I'm not sure if FB.api accepts plaintext responses, I believe it was designed for JSON responses.

In the future check your Browser Dev Tools to see what HTTP GET you are actually doing through the JS SDK